# How to access object scope inside scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a function `foo` which is called on `window.scroll`. I want to access the object variables inside foo, for example i want to print the value of hello from the parent object.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nkd88c6w/)

```
 var Object = {
 hello: "hello",

  foo: function(e){
      alert(this.hello); //Prints undefined! I want to get this.hello
  },

  scrollListener: function(){
    var _this = this;
    $(window).scroll(_this.foo);
  },
};
```

Comment: According to JSFiddle, that code is correct when called with `Object.foo({});`

Comment: remove `.hello` from `this` and you'll see why. `this` in your context refers to `window`

Comment: i understand why this is not available. `this` refers to the scroll event

Answer (score 2):

I think wrapping `_this.foo` in an anonymous function will do the trick.

Use this in window.scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      _this.foo();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nkd88c6w/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solution

1) use `$.proxy` to do the trick.

`$(window).scroll( $.proxy(_this.foo,this) );`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1amnz8u5/1/)

2) Return the foo function and then call it.

```
foo: function(context) {
    var that = context;
    return function(e){ alert(that.hello); }
},

scrollListener: function(){
   var _this = this;
   $(window).scroll(_this.foo(_this));
},
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dem7shfw/3/)